# add new element in laravel collection object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to add new element in `$items` array, I don't want to use joins for certain reasons.

```
$items = DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT * FROM items WHERE items.id = '.$id.'  ;'));
foreach($items as $item){
    $product = DB::select(DB::raw(' select * from product
           where product_id = '. $id.';' ));

    $item->push($product);
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: use the `Push` method to add new element to collection something like `$items->push(you array here);`

Comment: this question/answer helped me but it is confused to call $items the collection… which contains _#items_, look at my question/answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78046080/add-an-object-in-laravel-eloquent-collection

Answer (score 186, accepted):

It looks like you have everything correct [according to Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-push), but you have a typo

```
$item->push($product);
```

Should be

```
$items->push($product);
```

`push` method appends an item to the end of the collection:

I also want to think the actual method you're looking for is `put`

```
$items->put('products', $product);
```

`put` method sets the given key and value in the collection

Comment: Laravel might want to consider calling this something like `pushWithKey(...)` to help with clarity

Comment: hi @Pastor Bones i am trying to put "customer_id" into a product model so i tried this method $cpr = Product::where('id' , $product)->first();
                
                  $cpr->put($customer->id, 'customer_id'); but it gives error Call to undefined method App\Models\Product::put() can u help me

Answer (score 18):

As mentioned above  if you wish to add as a new element your queried collection you can use:

```
    $items = DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT * FROM items WHERE items.id = '.$id.'  ;'));
    foreach($items as $item){
        $product = DB::select(DB::raw(' select * from product
               where product_id = '. $id.';' ));

        $items->push($product);
        // or 
        // $items->put('products', $product);
    }
```

but if you wish to add new element to each queried element you need to do like:

```
    $items = DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT * FROM items WHERE items.id = '.$id.'  ;'));
    foreach($items as $item){
           $product = DB::select(DB::raw(' select * from product
                 where product_id = '. $id.';' ));
    
          $item->add_whatever_element_you_want = $product;
    }
```

`add_whatever_element_you_want` can be whatever you wish that your element is named (like product for example).

Answer (score 13):

If you want to add item to the beginning of the collection you can use [prepend](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-prepend):

```
$item->prepend($product, 'key');
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add a product into the array you can use:

```php
$item['product'] = $product;
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this if you are using array called for 2 tables. Example you have,
`$tableA['yellow']` and `$tableA['blue']` . You are getting these 2 values and you want to add another element inside them to separate them by their `type`.

```
foreach ($tableA['yellow'] as $value) {
    $value->type = 'YELLOW';  //you are adding new element named 'type'
}

foreach ($tableA['blue'] as $value) {
    $value->type = 'BLUE';  //you are adding new element named 'type'
}
```

So, both of the tables value will have new element called `type`.

Answer (score 1):

This is what i would do...

```
$items = Item::find($id);
foreach($items as $item){
    $product = Product::find($id);
    $item->product = $product;
}
```

This would assign $product to each $item

Answer (score -2):

```
$item = collect();
$item->push($product);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.