# Fill data from Model and function into an Associative array in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5, associative-array

I'm working with Laravel for the first time. I have a scenario where I have a Products table which contains basic details of a Product (Corrugated Box) like length, breadth, height etc. Some other details of the product is computed using the basic details within a function.

My code in the Controller looks like this:

```
public function viewProducts() {

        /* Fetch basic details */        
        $prod_specs = DB::table('master_products')
                ->join('part_types', 'master_products.part_type_id', '=', 'part_types.id')
                ->join('box_types', 'master_products.box_type_id', '=', 'box_types.id')
                ->select('master_products.*', 'part_types.part_type', 'box_types.box_type')
                ->get();

        /* Calculate Specs and add them to the array */
        $i = 1;
        $products = array();

        foreach ($prod_specs as $spec) {
            $products['product_code'] = $spec->product_code;
            $products['part_type_id'] = $spec->part_type_id;
            $products['box_type_id'] = $spec->box_type_id;
            $products['length'] = $spec->length;
            $products['breadth'] = $spec->breadth;
            $products['height'] = $spec->height;
            $products['ply'] = $spec->ply;
            $products['gsm_a_base'] = $spec->gsm_a_base;
            $products['gsm_a_flute'] = $spec->gsm_a_flute;
            $products['gsm_b_base'] = $spec->gsm_b_base;
            $products['gsm_b_flute'] = $spec->gsm_b_flute;
            $products['gsm_top'] = $spec->gsm_top;

            $products['roll_size'] = $this->calcRollSize($spec->height, $spec->breadth, $spec->ply, $spec->part_type_id, $spec->box_type_id);
        }

        return view('/layouts/masters/products-master', ['products' => $products]);
    }

    /* Calculate Roll Size */

    private function calcRollSize($height, $breadth, $ply, $partTypeID, $boxTypeID) {
         /* Some calculation */
         return $rollSize;
   }
```

I want to return `$products` to my view and be able to access the basic details as well as the calculated details. Please help me achieve this.

**UPDATE**

I tried:

```
$products = DB::table('master_products')
                ->join('part_types', 'master_products.part_type_id', '=', 'part_types.id')
                ->join('box_types', 'master_products.box_type_id', '=', 'box_types.id')
                ->select('master_products.*', 'part_types.part_type', 'box_types.box_type')
                ->get();

        /* Calculate Specs and add them to the collection */
        foreach ($products as $product) {
            $rollSize = $this->calcRollSize($product->height, $product->breadth, $product->ply, $product->part_type_id, $product->box_type_id);
            $products->put('roll_size', $rollSize); 
        }
```

and got this exception: **`Call to a member function put() on a non-object`**

But according to [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33828769/add-new-element-in-laravel-collection-object) question's accepted answer it's supposed to work. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Using `return view('/layouts/masters/products-master')->with(compact('products'));` you can access the full `$products` variable you built in the products-master view

Comment: Thanks...But is the rest of my syntax correct ? And is this the best way of doing it ?

Comment: Well you could take a more "Object Oriented approach" but it's out of the scope for this question. It kind of depends on your data logic but you could avoid in some way populating the whole $products array since you are basically turning an object into an array right? Maybe you can try **(array) $yourObject;** so you dont have to manually set all the values for the array before setting the calcRollSize value. But then again: is transforming an object into an array what you **really** want?

Comment: No. I just want to pass the object $products and be able to access the Basic & Computed values from the Model and the functions. Can you please show me how I can do it !!

Comment: The computed values can't be easily object-orientified unless you create a Model for the "prod_specs" (which only you know if it's the best suit for your needs). In any case if you want to make your code a lil bit more elegant you could try replacing the foreach for: **$products = (array) $spec** to avoid all the repetitive initializations and then you can assign the computed $products['roll_size'] value like you do in your current code