# Collection->put() not working in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-collection

I'm working with Laravel for the first time. I have a scenario where I have a Products table which contains basic details of a Product (Corrugated Box) like length, breadth, height etc. Some other details of the product is computed using the basic details within a function.

My code in the Controller looks like this:

**Controller:**

```
$products = DB::table('master_products')
            ->join('part_types', 'master_products.part_type_id', '=', 'part_types.id')
            ->join('box_types', 'master_products.box_type_id', '=', 'box_types.id')
            ->select('master_products.*', 'part_types.part_type', 'box_types.box_type')
            ->get();

    /* Calculate Specs and add them to the collection */
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $rollSize = $this->calcRollSize($product->height, $product->breadth, $product->ply, $product->part_type_id, $product->box_type_id);
        $products->put('roll_size', $rollSize); 
    }

return view('/layouts/masters/products-master', ['products' => $products]);
```

**View:**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Sl.No.</th>
                    <th>Product Code</th>
                    <th>Part Type</th>
                    <th>Box Type</th>
                    <th>Length</th>
                    <th>Breadth</th>
                    <th>Height</th>
                    <th>Ply</th>
                    <th>Roll Size</th>
                    <th>A-Base</th>
                    <th>A-Flute</th>
                    <th>B-Base</th>
                    <th>B-Flute</th>
                    <th>Top</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>                    
                @foreach($prod_specs as $prod_spec)
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $prod_spec->product_code; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $prod_spec->part_type; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $prod_spec->box_type; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $prod_spec->length; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $prod_spec->breadth; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $prod_spec->height; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $prod_spec->ply; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $prod_spec->roll_size; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $prod_spec->gsm_a_base; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $prod_spec->gsm_a_flute; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $prod_spec->gsm_b_base; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $prod_spec->gsm_b_flute; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $prod_spec->gsm_top; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php $i++; ?>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

I got this exception: **Call to a member function put() on a non-object**

But according to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33828769/add-new-element-in-laravel-collection-object)'s accepted answer it's supposed to work. What am I missing here ?

**Update:**

Tried this

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $rollSize = $this->calcRollSize($product->height, $product->breadth, $product->ply, $product->part_type_id, $product->box_type_id);
    $product['roll_size'] = $rollSize; 
}
```

Got an error **`Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`**

Answer (score 1):

You're getting an array from Query Builder. Laravel collect() helper is your solution:

```
$products = collect(DB::table('master_products')
            ->join('part_types', 'master_products.part_type_id', '=', 'part_types.id')
            ->join('box_types', 'master_products.box_type_id', '=', 'box_types.id')
            ->select('master_products.*', 'part_types.part_type', 'box_types.box_type')
            ->get());
```

[More info](https://laravel.com/docs/master/helpers#method-collect)

Answer (score 0):

The [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries) does not return a collection when calling `get`, it returns an array:

> Like raw queries, the get method returns an array of results where each result is an instance of the PHP StdClass object.

If you want an Eloquent collection, you will need to use an Eloquent model or use the `collect()` helper function as @Martin suggests.

Comment: Oh okay. My bad. So in that case how can I add `roll_size` to the `$products` array ??

Comment: The same as you would add something to any other array: `$products['roll_size'] = $rollSize`

Comment: `dd($product)` inside your loop and update your question with the output.  Also note that, after this loop runs, there will be only _one_ index of `roll_size`.  You may need to rethink your design if you need an array of roll sizes.

Comment: The error description has `'products' => array(object(stdClass), 'roll_size' => '1671'`. Looks like I'm adding an array to an object. `var_dump($products)` says its an object

Comment: You're right Mr Jeff. I want to access `$products->roll_size` in my view..please suggest how do I do it

Answer (score 0):

The `put()` method sets the given `key` and `value` in the collection:

you are trying to save array object in `$rollSize`.

In model make `roll_size` serialize object if you want to store `rollSize` as array in database.