# add an object in laravel eloquent collection

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a class *Place* and sometimes, in my main Sample object, I have multiple places so I call Sample->places to send it to my view.
But for a new sample, I have no Place object in it, so I want to add one in the empty collection :

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#513 ▼ 
  #items: []
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
}
```

How to add in *items* collection array a new instance of *Place* ?

Answer (score 0):

my searches return this post [add new element in laravel collection object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33828769/add-new-element-in-laravel-collection-object) which was closed and is confusing because collection variable was named $items.

in my case with *sample* which have (or not) *place*, I solved by writing :

```php
$sample_places = $sample_record->places;
if ($sample_places->isEmpty()) {
    $sample_places->push(new Place());
}
```

so my collection have some places from databases (not empty) or go through the if and have an empty Place instance in *#items*

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#513 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => App\Models\Place {#500 ▶}
  ]
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
}
```

and I can give this collection to my view to render form to fill this first place.

Links :

- https://laravel.com/api/10.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html where you find push method
- https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-collections where push method is not explain